# Get statics from PHP class

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the static properties from a class without having to create an instance of the class?

```
$reflection   = new ReflectionObject( 'Foo' );
$staticProperties = $reflection->getStaticProperties();
```

Doing that throws an error.

```
ReflectionObject::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in test.php on line 19
```

This is php 5.5
The docs seem to show I should be able to pass a string..

http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php

```
Either a string containing the name of the class to reflect, or an object.
```

Any idea? Want to get them without having to token parse the file.

Comment: Use `ReflectionClass` instead

Comment: lol. Blame that on lack of sleep...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @PeeHaa pointed out, it is not `ReflectionObject` it is `ReflectionClass`.

New code:

```
$reflection   = new ReflectionClass( 'Foo' );
$staticProperties = $reflection->getStaticProperties();
```

Answer (score 0):

ReflectionObject gives information about an object instance. What you are looking for and linked in your question is ReflectionClass.

Answer (score 0):

This link is taken directly from the php reference: 
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticpropertyvalue.php

```
<?php
class Apple {
     public static $color = 'Red';
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('Apple');
var_dump($class->getStaticPropertyValue('color'));
?>
```

So here you can see you need a class and a name of the static property (the string that is requested)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ClassName::propertyName
```

Here it is:

```
ReflectionObject::getStaticProperties()
```